# Advertising before seeking a publisher

Tags: marketing, publishing, advertisements

I'm nearing competition of my first title and I'd like to seek out publishers but I'm also eager to show it off on social media.

Should I hold off until I've spoken to publishers or is it mostly harmless?

Comment: I think that this is more of an opinion-based question. This website is not a good fit for questions like that. You might want to ask it on a more discussion-oriented website like https://reddit.com/r/gamedev.